# Mouse wheel not working when over ScrollViewer's child controls

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, scrollviewer, mousewheel

I was kind of expecting my ScrollViewer's child controls to hand the MouseWheel events back up the the ScrollViewer automatically, and that's not the case.

I have a ScrollViewer with a ListBox in it.  If I manually resize the width of the ListBox to be less than the ScrollViewer, the MouseWheel works on all of the ScrollViewer but has no effect when the mouse is positioned above the ListBox.

What's the standard way to do this?  Do I put an event trigger on the ListBox that fires the event on the parent?  Do I handle and reroute the event in the code behind?

Comment: Answer is here: http://serialseb.blogspot.com/2007/09/wpf-tips-6-preventing-scrollviewer-from.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `ListBox`'s template has a `ScrollViewer` in it, so that `ScrollViewer` will be handling the events and stopping them from propagating up the visual tree.

What exactly are you trying to achieve by having a `ListBox` inside a `ScrollViewer`? Perhaps you need to re-template the `ListBox`, but it's impossible to say without further info.

Comment: I had no idea that the ScrollViewer was part of the ListBox's template, so I was under the assumption that I had to put the ListBox inside of a ScrollViewer.  Thanks.