# About re-templating correctly DataGrid

Tags: wpf, templates, datagrid, wpfdatagrid, scrollviewer

I recently had [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948780/wpf-scroll-focus-changing-problem) about scrolling and focus changing.

I solved it by adding in my `DataGrid` the following:

```
            <DataGrid.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>

                    <ItemsPresenter />
                </ControlTemplate>

            </DataGrid.Template>
```

The scrolling now works fine, but a new problem appeared: the `DataGrid`'s headers do not show anymore. It is actually logic, since now my `DataGrid` will only show an `ItemsPresenter` without taking care of the headers. I am therefore trying to define an appropriate template, showing first the headers and then the items in an `ItemsPresenter`, allowing me to scroll easily.
Am I just missing something, or is that a different property to override?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what the default DataGrid template looks like (in the Classic theme):

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
      BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
      BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
      SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
      Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
        <ScrollViewer   Focusable="false"
                Name="DG_ScrollViewer">
            <ScrollViewer.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Button Command="{x:Static DataGrid.SelectAllCommand}"
                                Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=CellsPanelHorizontalOffset}"
                                Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type DataGrid}, ResourceId=DataGridSelectAllButtonStyle}}"
                                Focusable="false"
                                Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=HeadersVisibility, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.All}}" />
                        <DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter Grid.Column="1" 
                                           Name="PART_ColumnHeadersPresenter"
                                           Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=HeadersVisibility, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Column}}"/>

                        <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" />

                        <ScrollBar Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar"
                                 Orientation="Vertical"
                                 Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
                                 ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"
                                 Value="{Binding Path=VerticalOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=OneWay}"
                                 Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"/>

                        <Grid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=NonFrozenColumnsViewportHorizontalOffset}"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ScrollBar Grid.Column="1"
                                       Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar"
                                       Orientation="Horizontal"
                                       Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
                                       ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"
                                       Value="{Binding Path=HorizontalOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=OneWay}"
                                       Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"/>

                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ScrollViewer.Template>
            <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Notice that it uses a `DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter`. You will want to add this to your template as well.

Comment: `DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter`. This is what I've been looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @matt I have a doubt about what is the use of this    <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=NonFrozenColumnsViewportHorizontalOffset}"/>