# Get and set the location of a row in a WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

For a WPF application that has multiple pages and supports navigation, I need to save and restore the current scrolling state of a DataGrid. As the exact rows in the view can change when the user comes back to the view, I want to save the selected item together with the screen offset it is displayed at. When the user comes back to the previous view, I still have the selected item and its screen offset in the ViewModel and need to restore it to the view, by scrolling the DataGrid so that the remembered item is at the same vertical offset again.

I have searched for several methods but found none at all. How would I even start doing this with WPF? I think I need to get the visible offset of an item, or a row by index, and scroll the DataGrid so that this item ends up at the remembered position.

Comment: So what happens when you use ScrollIntoView(object item, Column column)? Does this not scroll both the item and offset correctly?

Comment: You could go through the DataGrid's visual tree and get its ScrollViewer. Then use ScrollToVerticalOffset(int) and/or ScrollToHorizontalOffset(int) to get to where you want to be. Put this inside the Page's Loaded handler.

Comment: So you suggest scanning the visual tree to find the selected item and do loads of maths to determine the position on the screen (i. e. within the visible area). Is it safe to take the nth whatever item from the visual tree from the SelectedIndex n?

Comment: Hopefully it wouldn't be loads of math. ROWHEIGHT * someOffset was sort of along the lines of what I was thinking. But maybe that's just not a practical way for you to go about. Maybe give something a try?  Post some code? Have you tried the DataGrid's ScrollIntoView method? I'm not sure that will be enough for you because if I recall correctly, that will scroll the item to the 'top' of your grid. It might not have scrolled to that position when you left the page. But maybe that will do?

Comment: And I wasn't thinking you would find the item, I was thinking you could find the scrollviewer that is part of the DataGrid's default template (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976828/about-re-templating-correctly-datagrid).

Comment: Afaik, the row height is not constant. It might change with every row. So just using a multiple of it may lead to a very wrong position.

Comment: That's too bad. I was assuming your items would be fairly consistent with regards to the way they would affect their containing row/column/cell. Would have been handy and straightforward. Hmmm... *shrug* Try to code some ideas up, post that here. Not sure what else what to suggest, except perhaps having your rows always assume the worst case scenario for width/height.