# Capturing mouse wheel on listbox items

Tags: wpf, mousewheel, listboxitem

I have a listbox which is populated with a relatively small number of items. The items don't fit on the screen, so the listbox automatically gets a vertical scrollbar on the right. The scrollbar responds to the mouse wheel but the listbox items don't. How can I make the items respond to the mouse wheel?

Thanks in advance!

--Nacho

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189053/disable-mouse-wheel-on-itemscontrol-in-wpf. Also can see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer_methods

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid that the ListBox responds to mousewheel events, You want to handle the mousewheel event within the context of the ListBox element.

In that handler you can set e.Handled=true which will stop the event bubbling to the containing listbox.

You might as well put that statement in a containing element within the ListBoxItem.

Answer (score 0):

This selects items on a list box I have in a WPF window. As you turn the mouse wheel, a ListBox item is selected.
The ListBox gains focus before this and the first item is selected already.

In the class file put:

```
private void ListBox1_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    int cap = (ListBox1.Items.Count) - 1;
    int place = ListBox1.SelectedIndex;
    int incre = e.Delta/120;
    place += incre;
    if (place > cap)
    {
        place = 0;
    }
    if (place < 0)
    {
        place = cap;
    }
    ListBox1.SelectedIndex = place;
    ListBox1.ScrollIntoView(itemNoresult1.SelectedItem);
}
```

In XAML properties for your list box put: `PreviewMouseWheel="ListBox1_MouseWheel"`