# Scrollview does not update

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling, oxyplot

I have a PlotView in a ScrollViewer:

```
<ScrollViewer Margin="0,25,0,0">
    <oxy:PlotView Model="{Binding myModel}" Height="2000" Margin="0,0,15,0" PreviewMouseWheel="ScrollViewer_PreviewMouseWheel" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

The PlotView implements zooming by scrolling. Since scrolling with the mouse wheel is handled by the ScrollViewer, I want to disable it.
I tried to catch the PreviewMouseWheel event of the ScrollViewer and zoom the PlotView by hand:

```
private void ScrollViewer_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;

    if (e.Delta > 0)
        myModel.ZoomAllAxes(1.2);
    else
        myModel.ZoomAllAxes(1 / 1.2);

    myModel.InvalidatePlot(false);
}
```

Unfortunately, the update of the model does not become visable until, the Scrollbar reaches the bottom or the top. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

See [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2189182/4303098), a similar situation I guess.

I guess you can  wrap your plot view in same way this solution suggests you to deal with listbox.